# How to change vertex color using a key in blender game engine?

Tags: game-engine

[image]I have a cube having vertex colors enabled, i want to increase and decrease the alpha color component of its vertices when i press up and down arrow keys respectively. How can i do this without writing a fragment shader, just by using Blender's Logic Editor?